# How do I pause email delivery to specific people in an Exchange Distribution List?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, distribution-lists

[Using **Exchange Admin Center** online; subsite of **Microsoft 365 Admin Center**]

I would like to temporarily suspend delivery of email to specific people on a Distribution List. This is a DL that contains people both inside and outside of the organization; the people to suspend are both inside and outside the org. I know I could remove them from the DL and then re-add them, but is there a "more elegant" way to do that?

Comment: `I know I could remove them from the DL and then re-add them, but is there a "more elegant" way to do that?` - No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly what joeqwerty has said above, remove and re-add these users in distribution list may be a better choice.

I have tried to create a transport rule to achieve this goal, but no luck. Once i use transport rule, all mails send to these specific users will be rejected.